# Vim Ctrl-[ stopped working

Tags: vim

The shortcut key `<C-[>` in Vim has stopped working for me. I've tried reinstalling Vim with default settings, which didn't work. I've uninstalled, removed _vimrc files and anything else that had 'vim' in the file name, but to no avail.

The `ESC` key works fine, so does `<C-c>`.

I've tried a few suggestions here that to do with reassigning mappings, and that didn't work as well.

I'm clueless as to what the problem might be and desperately need some pointers as to how to diagnose and possibly reclaim my `<C-[>` key as I highly depend on it to be efficient.

It's Windows, btw.

Comment: Does `<Esc>` work? And what is printed when you type the commands `:map <C-[>` and `:imap <C-[>`?

Comment: Yes, `<Esc>` works. Both commands return "no mapping found"

Comment: Also `<C-c>` works as well

Comment: Does `<C-[>` work in other programs?

Comment: Oh, and is this terminal Vim, GVIM, or both?!

Comment: both gVim and terminal Vim

Comment: Oh and yes, I have Vintageous plugin installed on Sublime Text and it works as expected

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `<C-]>`?

Comment: How about `<C-V> <C-[>`? What does that produce? (It should produce U+001B, which will appear as `^[`.)

Comment: `<C-v>` doesn't work for me as it pastes clipboard contents

Comment: @ArcaArtem `<C-Q>` then. Or `:unmap <C-V>` as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like the default keyboard language was to blame. My keyboard was set to "United Kingdom Extended", and changing it to "United Kingdom" has solved this issue, though I have to admit I don't know why, since `<C-[>` appeared to work elsewhere...